# How do i log-in with a POST request in a Django view?

Tags: python, django, request, python-requests

On a certain page of my Django project, i'm trying to add a feature where, when a page is loaded, a request is sent to an external Python script, this Python script will retrieve some data and send it as a response to the Django view, which should show it on the HTML using Jquery. To send the requests, i'm using the Request module.

I'm having some problems sending the response with the Json data to the Django view, here is what i tried:

Here is how the request is sent:

```
import requests

req = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview', json={"test": "testjson"})
print('SENT')
```

What i tried in the view:
def myTestView(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
    print(received_json_data)
    print('Received request')
```

I'm trying to print the response in my console just for debugging purposes. The problem is that i don't see the request being printed in the console. Instead, i only see this:

```
[24/Dec/2019 12:00:40] "POST /tv/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Dec/2019 12:00:40] "GET /account/login/?next=/tv/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23357
```

Which means that i have to add my credentials, since the view is `@login_required`. The problem is that this request is fired when the user loads the page or performs a certain operation, and the request will hold sensitive data. This task, however, can be performed by any user on the site, so i can't add the credentials of only one in my external request. How can i fix this? Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Well, you can make use of cookies/ sessions to manage state for each user.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: What are you using for starting your django server? It seems you are using gunicorn or some kind of wsgi worker. If you use the development server: `manage.py runserver`, you will see your `print` statements results in console.